# Creating pdf of a web page by using Apache PDFBOX

Tags: java, pdf-generation, pdfbox, web-content

Today i came to know about PDFBOX and founded it as a good library to create PDF files.

I got some sample codes from which i can get text from pdf files,writing a text to a pdf file etc.

But what my requirement is that i need to show the web page(one of my application) as a pdf with click of a button.

Is there any way to do it? I have searched a little bit but havent found anything useful.Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use JSPdf

URL: http://parall.ax/products/jspdf

This is javascript framework.

Comment: Hi rahul,thanks for the response.But PDFBOX is what suggested by my client to use